# Can I make plain/text mode the default when writing emails?

Tags: gmail, plaintext

Is possible to make it always plain/text mode when writing email or is there any other Linux email/free service provide text complete feature.

I am using Ubuntu 22. I use Gmail on Chrome web browser.

Comment: You probably need to add more detail to your question (particularly around what email client you use - ie whete does yhe OS come into this?)

Comment: Outlook (Windows) has an option to default all new emails to be in text.

Comment: @davidgo thanks. updated information.

Comment: Most desktop clients will do this. Thunderbird has a setting to do so.  Id be surprised if old text based client like pine/alpine will prefer text mode because they dont use a GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps for Gmail on web browser

1. Click the top left button "Compose"
2. Click the bottom right three dots button "More options"
3. Check "Plain text mode"
4. It seems if you don't uncheck "Plain text mode," when you write an email, you will always write the email in plain text mode.